# Train and validate using tensorflow estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have created a shallow NN using tf.estimator API. I would like to something similar to the hyperparameter search explained in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=948&v=eBbEDRsCmv4 at TensorFlow Dev Summit.

I could not find any updated documentation about how can you do this. I have the following code (I will try to simplify as much as possible):

```
# Define nn architecture
def neural_net(features):
    input_layer = tf.cast(features['x'], tf.float32)
    hidden_layer = nn_layer(input_layer, 10, 'hidden_layer', act=tf.nn.relu)
    out_layer = nn_layer(hidden_layer, 2, 'out_layer', act=tf.nn.relu)
    return out_layer

# Define model function
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    # Build the neural network
    logits = neural_net(features<9


    with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    # Define loss and optimizer
        loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(logits=logits, labels=labels)

    # Configure the Training
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)


nn_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn)


train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
            x={"x": train_data},
            y=train_labels,
            batch_size=100,
            num_epochs=None,
            shuffle=True)

nn_classifier.train(
        input_fn=train_input_fn,
        steps=20000
        )
```

Executing this code I can obtain the summary for the loss and observe it in Tensorboard. But imagine I want to obtain different curves. Let's say that I want to see how the loss evolves with the number of samples, so I would train two models with different sample size. Or two models with a different architecture... whatever.

How can I get these two curves in Tensorboard?

Answer (score 1):

Save all models to a subdirectory of a parent directory and pass this parent directory as the logdir in tensorboard; this will put all curves in the same graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run any architecture you want. And the validation and train data will be saved in your working folder and are viewable inside TensorBoard. There's filter to pick for all the models architecture that you've ran.

[image: Filter]